# AWS account:ListRegions 403 forbidden via PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I need to list all regions of an AWS account (part of an organization).
I plan to use "AccountClient" with "ListRegions".

I connected to the account via a role named 'myrole' witch is 'AdministratorAccess' (so got account:listregion persmission) but I'm getting a 403 response with message :

User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/myrole/session_70429 is not authorize (truncated...)\n AccessDeniedException (client): User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/myrole/session_70429 is not authorized to perform: account:ListRegions

What is wrong in my code ? Why I don't have access to that information with that role ?

```
<?php 

$stsClient = new StsClient([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'eu-central-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'xxx',
        'secret' => 'yyy',
    ],
]);

$random = rand(10000, 99999);

$response = $stsClient->assumeRole([
    'RoleArn' => 'myrole',
    'RoleSessionName' => "session_$random",
]);

$credentials = new Credentials(
    $response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    $response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    $response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
);

$client = new AccountClient([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => 'eu-central-1',
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);

$r = $client->ListRegions(["AccountId" => '12345678']);

return $r['Regions'];
```

Comment: Which AWS SDK version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.275.5

Comment: I just update to the latest version 3.283 and I got the same error message. What surprise me is that I have generating AccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey and SessionToken via PHP code, and use it in CLI just to test and it is working fine. I conclude my creds are "ok" but PHP return an error... Any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you please also show the trust policy added for that role?

Comment: I guess you ask for "trust relationships" on the role ? Here is the json I can see on the "main account" where the organization is set
{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::12345678:root"},"Action":"sts:AssumeRole","Condition":{}}]}